# monitoring tool that can display bandwith for a specific period in time

Tags: networking, monitoring

i'm looking for a monitoring tool that can display network bandwidth usage for a specific period in time (working hours) it has to work on a linux platform

We are using MRTG en routers2.cgi now , but it seems that it is only possible to display traffic for 1 hole day week, month or year.

Anny suggestions ?  I found PRTG but thats only works on a windows platform

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Cacti](https://www.cacti.net/), it lets you specify your graphs, [here is an example](https://web.archive.org/web/20170510125917/http://www.cacti.net:80/image.php?image_id=39).
Supports SNMP and a PHP Poller which you can use to write scripts that collect data.

[image]

Comment: +1 for cacti -- but bear in mind there a packages out there that are easier to get your head around.

Comment: I totally agree, another good choice is Munin..

Answer (score 1):

Do you have netflow on your routers? You can send statistics with netflow over SNMP to more than one system.

- www.manageengine.com [free and quite easy to set up]

Answer (score 1):

Cacti is great for this (as mentioned above).  If you want something that will also act as an all round monitoring package, I'd recommend [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) instead.  Zabbix will allow you to drill down in to any of the graphed data, looking at hours, days, weeks etc. etc; alongside being able to monitor pretty much any server or system metric you can conceive of.